# Spring Boot conditonally enable DataSourceAutoConfiguration based on system property

Tags: spring-boot

I have the following dependency in my project and have @SpringBootApplication in my main class
            spring-boot-starter-data-jpa
Is there any way to conditionally enable the spring boot datasourceautoconfiguration class based only when a Env property/System property is present.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It appears that if you define the property "spring.datasource.initialize" to false, the initialization logic will be skipped.

If you look at the DataSourceAutoConfiguration definition, it loads in configuration properties...

[image]

That DataSourceProperties has an attribute named "initialize", and it appears this is referenced in the DataSourceInitializer default implementation...

[image]

I read that as being able to use a property to skip datasource initialization.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

How about extending `DataSourceAutoConfiguration` with annotation `@ConditionalOnProperty`? You can exclude the original `DataSourceAutoConfiguration` from spring and make your own implementation part of your application. Such as,

```
@Configuration
@ConditiaonalOnProperty(value = "datasource.property.anything",matccchIfMissing==true)
public class DataSourceInit extends DataSourceAutoConfiguartion {
}
```

Add `exclude` on your spring application class as:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Comment: Hi Gemini, thanks. am able to get the application up successfully when datasource.property.anything is set to true...But when it is turned off(set to false), it is failing when loading HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration class. I came back and added @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class}). And now it is working when set to false but failing when set to true.

Comment: It is certain that it will be fine if you exclude all of them when you don't want to enable `DataSourceAutoConfiguration`. What would the failure be if your `datasource.property.anything` had been set to false? In my experience, `@ConditionalOnProperty` will decide whether class `HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration` should be loaded. Otherwise, would you please publish your project to github or just mail it to me? I'd like to do some more research on it. And I'm going to publish any useful information if I've achieved.

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude auto-configurations using the `spring.autoconfigure.exclude` property. You could set that property using a system property:

```
-Dspring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
```

You could also set it using the `SPRING_AUTOCONFIGURE_EXCLUDE` environment variable.